# How to restore old nautilus reaction to keyboard input

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, keyboard

Since Ubuntu 13.04 nautilus behaves different when typing. Before, the cursor moved to the file in current directory which matched the typed letters. Since 13.04, nautilus searches in all subdirectories. I don't like this, because it makes keyboard navigation nearly impossible. How to restore the old behavior?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and an option to turn this on would be good, so I'll be watching the answers :)